# Spark 1.6 java.io.IOException: Filesystem closed

Tags: java, scala, hadoop, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I have a strange issue. **I'm not closing file system by .close() or .abort()**.
Locally my application is working perfectly, but when I try to do spark-submit on cluster I have got a lot of Exceptions

```
> ERROR scheduler.LiveListenerBus: Listener EventLoggingListener threw an exception
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor14.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.EventLoggingListener$$anonfun$logEvent$3.apply(EventLoggingListener.scala:150)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.EventLoggingListener$$anonfun$logEvent$3.apply(EventLoggingListener.scala:150)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.EventLoggingListener.logEvent(EventLoggingListener.scala:150)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.EventLoggingListener.onApplicationEnd(EventLoggingListener.scala:196)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.SparkListenerBus$class.onPostEvent(SparkListenerBus.scala:54)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.LiveListenerBus.onPostEvent(LiveListenerBus.scala:31)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.LiveListenerBus.onPostEvent(LiveListenerBus.scala:31)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ListenerBus$class.postToAll(ListenerBus.scala:55)
    at org.apache.spark.util.AsynchronousListenerBus.postToAll(AsynchronousListenerBus.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.util.AsynchronousListenerBus$$anon$1$$anonfun$run$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(AsynchronousListenerBus.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.util.AsynchronousListenerBus$$anon$1$$anonfun$run$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(AsynchronousListenerBus.scala:72)
    at org.apache.spark.util.AsynchronousListenerBus$$anon$1$$anonfun$run$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(AsynchronousListenerBus.scala:72)
    at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:57)
    at org.apache.spark.util.AsynchronousListenerBus$$anon$1$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(AsynchronousListenerBus.scala:71)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrStopSparkContext(Utils.scala:1182)
    at org.apache.spark.util.AsynchronousListenerBus$$anon$1.run(AsynchronousListenerBus.scala:70)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Filesystem closed
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.checkOpen(DFSClient.java:858)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream.flushOrSync(DFSOutputStream.java:2350)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream.hflush(DFSOutputStream.java:2296)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataOutputStream.hflush(FSDataOutputStream.java:130)
    ... 20 more
```

But application is still running, until I have got. This error kills my app.

```
> ERROR util.Utils: Uncaught exception in thread Thread-3
java.io.IOException: Filesystem closed
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.checkOpen(DFSClient.java:858)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.getFileInfo(DFSClient.java:2120)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$20.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1253)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$20.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1249)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.getFileStatus(DistributedFileSystem.java:1249)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.exists(FileSystem.java:1417)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.EventLoggingListener.stop(EventLoggingListener.scala:224)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$stop$8$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1744)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$stop$8$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1744)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$stop$8.apply$mcV$sp(SparkContext.scala:1744)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryLogNonFatalError(Utils.scala:1220)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.stop(SparkContext.scala:1743)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$3.apply$mcV$sp(SparkContext.scala:604)
    at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHook.run(ShutdownHookManager.scala:267)
    at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager$$anonfun$runAll$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(ShutdownHookManager.scala:239)
    at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager$$anonfun$runAll$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ShutdownHookManager.scala:239)
    at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager$$anonfun$runAll$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ShutdownHookManager.scala:239)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:1818)
    at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager$$anonfun$runAll$1.apply$mcV$sp(ShutdownHookManager.scala:239)
    at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager$$anonfun$runAll$1.apply(ShutdownHookManager.scala:239)
    at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager$$anonfun$runAll$1.apply(ShutdownHookManager.scala:239)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:161)
    at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager.runAll(ShutdownHookManager.scala:239)
    at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager$$anon$2.run(ShutdownHookManager.scala:218)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ShutdownHookManager$1.run(ShutdownHookManager.java:54)
```

The last error is totally randomly, but it occurs 90% times when I'm using my app. Can be there be some with cluster configuration or my code is wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If the FileSystem is closed somewhere , the error will also occur when you use it again.